# Two questions about limits (in an exercise about the axiomatic definition of entropy)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, information-theory, entropy

I have two questions about limits (these questions arise from a proof that can be found in [Page 43 and 44 respectively](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/42d6/a9e258cdeddd7791614f502410f2b837a129.pdf)).

I will try to make clear the assumptions of each question, since they are located in a quite complicated proof. That is, I will write all hypothesis that are in the proof.

First question:

> Suppose that $v_m \rightarrow 0$.
>
> How to prove that $$\lim_{M \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{\sum_{m=2}^M mv_m}{\sum_{m=1}^M m} = 0 \quad ?$$

UPDATE: Solved! (Using Stolz's Theorem) Please see next question below.

Second question:

> How to prove that
>
> $$\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{b_n}\alpha_i}{\log_2(n)}=0$$
>
> given that $$\lim_{m \rightarrow +\infty}\alpha_m = 0$$ and $$b_n \leq p\left( \frac{\log_2(n)}{\log_2(p)}+1 \right),$$ where $p$ is a prime number (constant).
>
> Suggestion given in the book: the numerator has at most $o(\log_2(n))$ terms $\alpha_i$. (I think that this is false, since the quotient between the numerator and $\log_2(n)$ is not zero...)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please separate the questions in different posts

Comment: The first is an application of [Stolz's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem), which can be proved [like this](https://www.math.ksu.edu/~nagy/snippets/stolz-cesaro.pdf) For the first, Stolz says that the limit is the same a the limit of $\frac{mv_m}{m}=v_m\to0$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing Stolz's Theorem, I did not know it.

Comment: What is $t_n$ in equation $2.127$? Is it just a typo that should be $b_n$?

Comment: I think so, there are some typos but it is the best / more complete proof that I found

Comment: That book is full of typos. The proof they want should go something like this: The sum for $g(n)$ is really the one on $2.125$ in which $g(n^{(k)})=0$, for $k$ as in $2.126$. This double summation in $2.125$ are sums of sums of disjoint chunks, that go from $Pn^{(k)}$ to $n$. Once you make this observation, you can apply Stolz. In the numerator you will get $\alpha_{n+1}$ and a sum of $\alpha_i$ from $i=c_{n+1}$ to $c_n$, where $c_n$ is the right-hand side of $2.128$. Now you can bound that sum by $max(|\alpha_i|)$ time $c_{n+1}-c_n$, where the maximum is for $i$ in the interval above. ...

Comment: ...  Since $\frac{c_{n+1}-c_n}{\log(n+1)-\log(n)}$ is bounded and $c_n\to\infty$, then $\max(a_i)\frac{c_{n+1}-c_n}{\log(n+1)-\log(n)}$ tends to $0$. Therefore, by Stolz's theorem, the original limit $\frac{g(n)}{\log(n)}$ tends to zero.

Comment: I have to think a lot about this, since the definition of the $n^{(k)}$ is wrong. I suspect that what the book wants to define is $n^{(k+1)}=\lfloor n^{(k)}/p \rfloor$ with $n^{(0)} = n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly $\frac {b_n} {log_2 (n)}$ is bounded. Also $\lim \alpha_m =0$ implies that $\frac {\sum_1 ^{N} \alpha_i} {N} \to 0$ as $N \to \infty$. Let $|\frac {\sum_1 ^{N} \alpha_i} {N}| < \epsilon$ for $N \geq m$. If $b_n >m$ then $\frac {\sum_1 ^{b_n} \alpha_i} {b_n} < \epsilon$. Now multiply and divide by $\log_2 (n)$ and use the boundedness of $\frac {b_n} {log_2 (n)}$. Finally, to handle the case $b_n \leq m$ simply note that the numerator remains bounded and the denominator $\log_2 (n) \to \infty$. [ The numerator can take only the values $\alpha_1$,  $\alpha_1+\alpha_2$,...,$\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\cdots+\alpha_m$ so it has a bound independent of $n$].

Comment: Thanks for answering, I don't see the last part where you say that if $b_n \leq m$ (I assume that it is not $b_m$ here) the numerator remains bounded. Can you explain this with some more details?

Comment: @Leafar I have edited my answer to make the last part more explicit.